# United Travel Ready Center rejecting COVID-19 Vaccine Documentation

Tags: international-travel, covid-19, united-airlines

I am flying to Japan via United, and their Travel Ready Center is rejecting my vaccine documentation even though I am fully vaccinated. What's wrong?

Comment: What sort of rejection message did you receive? For example, are they saying that your documentation is illegible? That it is missing required doses? That it is a forgery?

Comment: @RobertColumbia as far as I remember United doesn't provide an error message. It's basically "yes" and "no". When I had an issue I needed to call them

Comment: Can you Post exactly what United said?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You may notice that your first and middle name is merged in the name field they've forced upon you. Bad programmers.

This will obviously not match a US COVID-19 Vaccine Record Card, and so your card will be rejected.

To solve this, in the United Airlines app, upload your vaccine documentation in your profile > TSA Precheck®️ and travel documents > COVID-19 Vaccine Documentation

This one does not merge your first and middle name together.
Go back to the Travel Ready Center and upload your vaccine documentation again.
This time, a pop-up will appear, allowing you to use the documentation you previously uploaded, without uploading a new file.
Documentation verification should pass this time, allowing you to check-in using the app.

Failing this, you need to physically go to check-in or the gate with your documentation and they'll sort the mess out for you

Comment: **Very** good question and self-answer pair! Welcome to [travel.se] and well done, mate, well done!

Comment: As a programmer I feel mildly insulted. It's less the choice of programmers, and more the issue of decades (probably close to half a century) old legacy systems which did not get updated when people realized they need to handle anything but the most basic of names.

Comment: Also as a programmer, it's imperative to test various use cases and not ship broken products while requiring their use in a mission critical application

Comment: @I'llEatMyHat That's why working with names sucks. UUID's for everyone?